# VB.NET SetAttribute in WebBrowser doens't work

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control, setattribute

I did some research previously, but all the answers do not **work**.
The "value" attribute exists in the element but does not **appear** in the webBrowser, nor in the input. 
This is my code until then, I need the webBrowser to **read an html file**, then load your answers or values ​​from your inputs from a database.

**PS**: 
My application is built in real time, there is no webbrowser control on the screen, it is created shortly after reading the html file and only then it is placed inside a panel.

```
    Dim webBrowser As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser
    Dim _doc As HtmlDocument
    Dim htmlPath As String = "C:\ePrimeCare\Platis\Debug\Protocolos\" + 
    nomeProtocolo + "_" + idSistema.ToString() + ".html"
    webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    webBrowser.Navigate(htmlPath)
    _doc = webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(False)
    'webBrowser.DocumentText = IO.File.ReadAllText(htmlPath).ToString()
    'webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(False)
    'RetornaRespostasAnteriores(idSistema, idFicha, nomeProtocolo, _doc, Convert.ToDateTime(dtVisita))
    _doc.Title = nomeProtocolo
    _doc.Write(IO.File.ReadAllText(htmlPath).ToString())
    Dim carregaRespostas As CarregarRespostaProtocoloHTML = New CarregarRespostaProtocoloHTML
    Dim respostas As DataTable = carregaRespostas.BuscarRespostasProtocoloAnterior(idFicha, idSistema, dtVisita)

    Dim idopcaoitem As String = 0
    Dim idsetitem As String = 0
    Dim value As DataRow()
    Dim strArr As String()
    For Each element As HtmlElement In _doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        Dim type As String = element.GetAttribute("type")
        Select Case type
            Case "text"
                strArr = element.GetAttribute("id").Split("_") 'For get the two ids
                idopcaoitem = strArr(0)
                value = respostas.Select(("IDOPCAOITEM = " + idopcaoitem.ToString()))
                If value.Length > 0 Then
                    element.SetAttribute("value", value(0)(2).ToString())'Here i try to set the value, but does not work
                End If
            Case "radio"
                Debug.WriteLine("Input de radio")
            Case "checkbox"
                Debug.WriteLine("Input de checkbox")
            Case "hidden"
                Debug.WriteLine("Input de hidden")
            Case Else
                Debug.WriteLine("Outro input")
        End Select
    Next
    _doc.Write(IO.File.ReadAllText(htmlPath).ToString())
    webBrowser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
    webBrowser.Dock = Dock.Fill
    pnlMain.Controls.Add(webBrowser)
```

Comment: Why are you navigating to the file and then creating a new document only to load the file again? Remove the latter and stick with only navigating to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your document rewriting and the refresh you do at the end will overwrite any changes you made to it.

```
'Either of these will revert the document back to its original state.
_doc.Write(IO.File.ReadAllText(htmlPath).ToString())
webBrowser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
```

You don't even need to call `_doc.Write()` as `WebBrowser1.Navigate(htmlPath)` will work just as fine.

New code:

```
Dim webBrowser As New WebBrowser 'Shorthand statement.
Dim _doc As HtmlDocument
Dim htmlPath As String = "C:\ePrimeCare\Platis\Debug\Protocolos\" + 
nomeProtocolo + "_" + idSistema.ToString() + ".html"
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
webBrowser.Navigate(htmlPath)
_doc = webBrowser.Document 'Removed OpenNew().
_doc.Title = nomeProtocolo

Dim carregaRespostas As New CarregarRespostaProtocoloHTML 'Another shorthand statement.
Dim respostas As DataTable = carregaRespostas.BuscarRespostasProtocoloAnterior(idFicha, idSistema, dtVisita)

(...your variables...)

For Each element As HtmlElement In _doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")

    (...your code...)

Next

'(Removed _doc.Write() and Refresh() since they will undo all changes)

webBrowser.Dock = Dock.Fill
pnlMain.Controls.Add(webBrowser)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was stuck in this for 2 days! A silly logic error hahahaha

Comment: @CarlitoMurta : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project! :)